# Beginner wood carving tools

Tags: hand-tools, tool-selection, carving

I'm looking at starting some small wood carving projects as a hobby and would like to know if anybody has any tips regarding what tools I should buy, or what they've had good experience with?

I've had a look on amazon but I don't want to go ahead and buy some tools off the internet if they're not going to be good enough!

Comment: Ah thanks, I'll take a look at that. Didn't see it when asking the question.